# Balloon from float to sink?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, noble-gases

Everytime I walk by the balloon stall, I know that they use helium to make the balloons float in the air. But my problem is why when I leave the balloon aside, the balloon sinks to the bottom. Is there anything happen to the  helium inside?

Comment: some of the helium leaks out

Comment: maybe I don't understand your question properly, but helium can slowly pass through the wall of the balloon (depending upon the material used), or through an imperfectly sealed closure such as a knot.

Comment: Maybe the wall.

Comment: see: http://www.karaloon.com/en/home/quality-and-safety/balloonsheliumfloating-time.html

Comment: Helium gas is made from tiny atoms which effuse through the pores in the balloon, usually rubber has more pores than a foil balloon so will sink faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the balloon is fully inflated with helium its density (mass/volume) is less than that of the air around it, allowing it to float. Over time, some of the helium will "leak" out of the balloon. As the helium is released the mass of the balloon decreases slightly, but the volume decreases at a much faster rate, resulting in a balloon with a density greater than that of the air around it, which is why it falls to the ground.